# Writing to an i2C-bus with Node.js on Raspberry Pi

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer, i2c

I'm hoping someone can help me out.  I am making a website and hosting it on a Raspberry Pi 4 with Node.js (v 14.15.1) with Express that will be inside my R2D2 that I'm making.  I have the website up just fine and I'm getting the commands that I want into the Node.js server with socket.io.  That part works awesome.  The problem that I'm having is taking those strings and sending them out with i2c to the variouse Arduinos that I have in my droid.  .  I can send the strings with serial fine but want to use i2C so I can reach the various Arduinos.  I'm very much a noob and probably doing things the worst possible way but I would greatly appreciate some help.

Here is my i2c.js file's code:

```
const i2c = require('i2c-bus');


function i2CSend(ldp, coin, vu, maint, serialcommand, dp, cbi) {
  var ldpcommand = Buffer.from(ldp);
  var coincommand = Buffer.from(coin);
  var vucommand = vu;
  var maintcommand = maint;
  var serialcommand = serialcommand;
  var dpcommand = dp;
  var cbicommand = cbi;
  var sleepinterval = 50;
  bodyLEDI2C = 0x26;
  var bodyServoI2C = 0x27;
  var domeServoLEDI2C = 0x0a;
  var domeHPI2C = 0x19;
  var bodyStealhI2C = 0x09;
  const i2c1 = i2c.open(1, function (err) {
   if (err) {
    throw err;
   }
   console.log("open")

   if (ldpcommand.length >> 0 ){
     console.log("LDP Command length: " + ldpcommand.length);
     i2c1.i2cWrite(bodyLEDI2C, ldpcommand.length, ldpcommand, function (err){
     if (err){
       throw err;
     }
   })
 }  
   if (coincommand.length >> 0 ){
     console.log("Coin Command length: " + coincommand.length);
     i2c1.i2cWrite(bodyLEDI2C, coincommand.length, coincommand, function (err){
     if (err){
       throw err;
     }
   })
 }
});
};
module.exports = i2CSend;
```

Here's my index.js file's code:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const logger = require('./middleware/logger');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const socket = require('socket.io');
const serial = require('./serial');
var player = require('play-sound')(opts = {});
var i2c = require('./i2c');
const app = express();

//handlebars middleware
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({ defaulLayout: 'main' }));
app.set('view enine', 'handlebars');

//body parser middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

var options =  {
  etag: true,
  lastModified: true,
  maxAge: 55111512312,
  setHeaders:  (res, path) => {

      res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');

  }
};

//Set a static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), options));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

var server = app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));

//Socket setup
var io = socket(server);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('made Socket Connection', socket.id);

  socket.on('command', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    var ldp = data.ldpcommandstring;
    var coin = data.coincommandstring;
    var vu = data.vucommandstring;
    var maint = data.mcommandstring;
    var serialcommand = data.serialcommandstring;
    var dp = data.dcommandstring;
    var cbi = data.icommandstring;
    // sleep(500).then(() => { serial(ldp, coin, vu, maint, serialcommand, dp, cbi); });

    // sleep(500).then(() => { i2c(ldp, coin, vu, maint, serialcommand, dp, cbi); });
   i2c(ldp, coin, vu, maint, serialcommand, dp, cbi);

    // sleep(500).then(() => { serial(coin); });

    // console.log("Coin Command: " + coin);
    // serial(ldp);
    // serial(coin);
  });
});

// player.play('./public/sounds/mp3/008 gen-8.mp3', { afplay: ['-v', 0.3] }, function (err) {

// });

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
};
```

I've commented out the serial commands in this index.js file for now.  It does work when uncommented.

I can get it to work when both the "ldpcommand" and "coincommand" have values in them, but when only 1 does, the server crashes with an error of "TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object" That's why I am checking to see if the buffer is empty or not.  (At least I think I'm checking).